# If WPF Richtextbox Highlight word contains hyphen,thin line shown in the word?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, highlighting, cpu-word

I am working in WPF RichTextBox.I have highlighted each word,using the below code.its works fine.But the word contains hyphen means,the highlighted word has some thin lines between the hyphen.

```
string SelectHighlightWord(RichTextBox rtb, int offset, int length)
{       
    TextRange fullRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    fullRange.ClearAllProperties();
    TextPointer startSelect = fullRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(offset);
    TextPointer endSelect = startSelect.GetPositionAtOffset(length);
    TextRange textRange = rtb.Selection;
    textRange.Select(startSelect, endSelect);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(m_backgroundColor));
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(m_foregroundColor));
    FrameworkContentElement fce = (startSelect.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
    if (fce != null)
    {
        fce.BringIntoView();
    }

    return rtb.Selection.Text;
}
```

Note : I have added images for better understanding.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: Why this Happened.Anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your window setting `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode` on `Ideal`? If so, try setting `Display`.